# Where to submit an Apple Watch app on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created an Apple Watch application using XCode 6.3 for iOS SDK 8.3. I tried to upload it to the `itunesconnect.apple.com` site. I can't find any options to upload Apple Watch apps. There are options only for iOS apps and OS X apps.

Please guide me with this.

Comment: please give more detail like your IDE (Xcode or?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**2019 Update**

As of watchOS 6.0 it is possible to create apps that run on the watch without the need to install a corresponding app on the paired iOS device.

You can follow [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps#3226960) to convert an existing watch app into an independent watch app, or just create a new stand-alone watch app in Xcode.

The App Store Connect process is still essentially the same - Create an iOS app.  You do not need to provide any iOS app screenshots, only watch screen shots.

*Original answer*

Apple Watch apps are hosted inside an iOS app, as an iOS extension - so to submit an Apple Watch app you need to submit an iOS app.

From the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html)

> Apple Watch requires the presence of an iPhone to run third-party
>   apps. To create a third-party app, you need two separate bundles: a
>   WatchKit app (that runs on Apple Watch) and a WatchKit extension (that
>   runs on the user’s iPhone). The WatchKit app contains only the
>   storyboards and resource files associated with your app’s user
>   interface. The WatchKit extension contains the code for managing the
>   WatchKit app’s user interface and for responding to user interactions.
>
> Because a WatchKit app extends the behavior of your existing iOS app, the WatchKit app and WatchKit extension are bundled together and packaged inside your iOS app bundle. During installation of your iOS app, the system prompts the user to install the WatchKit app when a paired Apple Watch is present.

When you submit your hosting iOS app to App Store you have an option to provide Apple Watch application screen shots to go along with your main app screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have created the application only for Apple Watch and i have not created any application design for iPhone. What will i upload for iphone screen shots ?? Is it necessary to create the same app for iphone too ??

Comment: It is not possible to create an Apple Watch only app at this time - You must have an existing app of some description to host the Apple Watch app

Comment: Is this possible to submit only iOS App? (my Application support iOS and Apple watch both)